# A elegant way to call functions from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, linter

I have something like this:

```js
function removeProduct(dataProduct) {
  console.log(dataProduct)
}
```

```html
<button data-shop-listing="{'foo': 'fooData'}" type="button" onclick="removeProduct(this.getAttribute('data-shop-listing'));">Remove</button>
```

Everything looks fine, right? The problem is I have no-unused-vars linter activated and it is a requirement not to turn it off.

what would be an elegant approach to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `<button data-shop-listing="{'foo': 'fooData'}" type="button" onclick="removeProduct(this)">Remove</button>` using `function removeProduct(but){
   var product = JSON.parse(but.getAttribute("data-shop-listing")); ...
}` If you have jQuery you do not need the JSON.parse, just $(this).data("shop-listing").foo - however this question is better asked at codereview

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense but is the problem with the linter having issues with the function? If so could you change it to `var removeProduct = function(dataProduct) {console.log(dataProduct)}`

Comment: Then it won't work because functions are working with an instance of another class.

Comment: Create the function like this: `window.removeProduct = function(dataProduct)...`

Comment: @Cristy I read is not very efficient to have global functions. In this case is the only solution to the problem?

Comment: @superTramp Your function is global anyway... it does exactly the same thing, only that the linter won't show an error.